# How can I fix a TypeError on a code calculating the limit of a natural log function?

Tags: python, typeerror, limit

Right now I'm trying to code the limit of the function: 4ln(2x+3)-1. This is what I've coded so far:

```
# import sympy 
from sympy import * 
import numpy as np
def function(x):
    return np.log(x)
  
x = symbols('x')
expr = 4*np.log(2*x+3)-1;
    
print("Expression : {}".format(expr)) 
      
# Use sympy.limit() method 
limit_expr = limit(expr, x, 0)  
      
print("Limit of the expression tends to 0 : {}".format(limit_expr))
```

I keep getting a `TypeError` on line 8, but I can't manage to fix it.

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'log'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-188-eba48ced061f> in <module>
      6 
      7 x = symbols('x')
----> 8 expr = 4*np.log(2*x+3)-1;
      9 
     10 print("Expression : {}".format(expr))

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Add which has no callable log method
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: The math functions in the `numpy` module are for performing calculations with actual numbers.  You have to use the corresponding functions from `sympy` to work with symbolic variables.

Comment: We need [the full error traceback, not just an explanation of the error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough). Copy and paste, formatted as code - [don't post a screenshot](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

@jasonharper has the right idea, so I'm writing up the comment as an answer.

> The math functions in the numpy module are for performing calculations with actual numbers. You have to use the corresponding functions from sympy to work with symbolic variables.

What happens is that while ordinary mathematical operators work fine with Sympy (they turn the magical placeholder for a variable into a magical placeholder for a basic mathematical expression in terms of that placeholder), it isn't possible for Sympy to do this with functions. You can't have the arguments to a function overload the behaviour of a function call (just imagine the madness that would ensue), so `np.log` actually attempts to determine the logarithm of this magical Sympy placeholder, immediately. This doesn't work because it's neither a numeric type, nor a Numpy array type (which Numpy functions handle with their own magic, by "broadcasting" to each element of the array).

You need to use Sympy's log function, which transforms a magical Sympy placeholder for an expression into the corresponding magical Sympy placeholder for the logarithm of that expression. This is [also called log, but defined by sympy instead of numpy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#log).